# Dockerfile not creating directories as root for jenkins image

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, dockerfile, snakeyaml

I'm trying to build a docker image for jenkins that automates the configuration of the server. I'd like to use yaml for my config files. For that I need to make snakeyaml available to the groovy grapes. Here is my docker file

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.107.3

ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /var/jenkins_home/files
RUN mkdir -p /var/jenkins_home/.groovy/grapes/org.yaml/snakeyaml/jars
RUN chown -R  jenkins:jenkins /var/jenkins_home/files
RUN chown -R  jenkins:jenkins /var/jenkins_home/.groovy/grapes/org.yaml/snakeyaml/jars

USER jenkins

COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt

COPY 03security.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/03security.groovy

COPY ivy-1.21.xml /var/jenkins_home/.groovy/grapes/org.yaml/snakeyaml/ivy-1.21.xml
COPY snakeyaml-1.21.jar  /var/jenkins_home/.groovy/grapes/org.yaml/snakeyaml/jars/snakeyaml-1.21.jar
COPY mainConfig.yml /var/jenkins_home/files/mainConfig.yml
COPY 03mainConfig.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/03mainConfig.groovy
```

I don't why I'm having this problem, but when I run the build I'm getting this error:

> chown: cannot access '/var/jenkins_home/files': No such file or directory

I've run similar commands in other images and not had this issue, but it won't let me create or access that file and I get the same error when I exclude it and try with only the .groovy/grapes path.

Any help in this is appreciated. Also, if you know a working solution to get snakeyaml(or another library) loaded into a jenkins docker image then I'd like to see that too.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's because **/var/jenkins_home/** is volume. If you run command **docker history jenkins/jenkins** you will see it.

```
<missing>           2 months ago        /bin/sh -c #(nop)  VOLUME [/var/jenkins_home]   0B
```

You can add your files you want to copy to **/var/jenkins_home**, to direcotry **/usr/share/jenkins/ref**

```
COPY *.xml /usr/share/jenkins/ref/
```

It means that all you xml files will be copied into /var/jenkins_home after container starts.